# Java Scanner not finding next line?

Tags: java, line

For some reason when I try scan a .txt file, it is failing to find any lines and thus causing the error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found     
   at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kayc0\\Desktop\\CkayBotBets\\mods.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream (file), "UTF-8");

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
         modsList.add(scanner.nextLine());       
         System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
     }
```

I do not close the scanner.
modsList is a List that I try add each line to so I can check if a mod exists in chat (user) matches one in the list, however the error is on System.out...

I checked the .txt file exists with the following:

```
 File f = new File("C:\\Users\\kayc0\\Desktop\\CkayBotBets\\mods.txt");

            if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
                System.out.println("file exists");
            }
```

Anyone any idea why the lines are not being read?

.txt contents:

```
abkayckay
kayc01
```

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently reading two lines instead of one, save the line you read to add to your list **and** display with the same line.

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    modsList.add(line);       
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You call `nextLine` tice. Change to:

```
 while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
         String value = scanner.nextLine()
         modsList.add(value);       
         System.out.println(value);
     }
```